# Find the value in range L to R in given array

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Given array **A**, and two indexes **L** and **R**,find the value of

> `Summation(AS[i]*AS[j]*AS[k])`

where `L<=i<j<k<=R` holds, and `AS` is the **sorted set** of all elements of `A` in range `L` to `R` inclusive.

Example:
Let `A=(4,4,1,6,1,3)` `L=0` and `R=3` gives `AS=(1,4,6)`, so `Ans=1*4*6=24`

I don't have any approach better than O(n^3) , which is very slow.
Please suggest me some faster approach.

Number of elements in A are upto 10^5.

Comment: are there any constraints for the subset?

Comment: L and R can be any arbitrary value. One thing is sure L<=R.

Comment: that's clear, but the point is wether there are any constraints for the subset. So far all you need to do is to sort the array and take any three values that have index <R and >L, which can be solved with the timecomplexity of the sorting algorithm

Comment: No. first I have to take elements from L to R from original array. Then remove duplicates, then sorting, then the formula.

Comment: Where in the question do you mention removing duplicates (other than showing one sample `AS` array, which could have just as easily been a typo)? Why could removing duplicates not be done at the same time as the sorting? Or at the absolute most, an extra `O(n)` step. Are `L` and `R` indices into the array `A`, or the array `AS`? You seem to be using them as both. I'm with @Paul; I don't see why the complexity should be any greater than that of the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

As the question commentators said, determining `AS` can be done by using a hash table `H`. You simply iterate through the elements of `A` from index `L` to `R` and you insert each element into `H`. The result should be the set of elements you need. You still need to sort the set. For that you maybe copy the elements of `H` into an array and sort that array. The result is `AS`. This should take no more than `O(NlogN)` steps, where `N=R-L`.

What the commentators did not say is how to compute the sum efficiently. It can be done in `O(N)` steps. Here is how.

We first make the following observation:

```
Sum(AS[j]*AS[k], a <= j < k <= b) = 
   1/2*(AS[a] + AS[a+1] + ... + AS[b])^2 - 
   1/2*(AS[a]^2 + AS[a+1]^2 + ... + AS[b]^2)
```

We expand our target sum as follows:

```
S = Sum(AS[i]*AS[j]*AS[k]) = 
   AS[L]   * Sum(AS[j]*AS[k], L+1 <= j < k <= R) +     (iteration     1)
   AS[L+1] * Sum(AS[j]*AS[k], L+2 <= j < k <= R) +     (iteration     2)
   ...
   AS[R-2] * Sum(AS[j]*AS[k], R-1 <= j < k <= R).      (iteration R-L-1)
```

We now apply the observation.

To determine the sums of the form `Sum(AS[j]*AS[k], a <= j < k <= b)` efficiently we can first compute

```
S1 = AS[L] + AS[L+1] + ... + A[R]
S2 = AS[L]^2 + AS[L+1]^2 + ... + A[R]^2
```

and then incrementally subtract the first term from each sum as we iterate through the elements of `AS` from from index `L` to `R-2`.

Thus, determining the sum you want can be done in `O(N)` steps after you determine `AS`. Provided that you use some comparison sort method the whole algorithm should take `O(|A|) + O(NlogN) + O(N)` steps.